# Docker composer parsing error for docker-compose.yml, at line 1, and column 1

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to setup selenoid and I'm having trouble with dockercomposer, it throws exception as below:

> yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a flow mapping in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1 expected ',' or '}', but got '{' in "./docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 1

```
when I try to run docker command "$ sudo docker-compose up -d"

I'm in the terminal with same folder where docker-compose.yml present and content is as below,

version: '3'
services:
 selenoid:
   network_mode: bridge
   image: aerokube/selenoid
   volumes:
     - "/docker:/etc/selenoid"
     - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
     - "/docker/video:/opt/selenoid/video"
   environment:
     - OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/selenium/video
     - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
   command: ["-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video"]
   ports:
     - "4444:4444"

I've also tried many online yml parsers and there is nothing wrong with yml file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry being late to answer my own post, there was nothing wrong with YML file, I should have created/edited it using programming editors such as IntelliJ, but I was editing and saving it using EditText. All worked fine after editing them and saving using IntelliJ in mac.